# react-native-network-info 'null is not an object'

Tags: react-native, unhandled-promise-rejection

It does not matter which function of the react-native-network-info I use, I always get a warning ([Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNNetworkInfo.getGatewayIPAddress')]) and the function does not return anything. See code sample.
I also already tried to do it exactly as in the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-network-info):

```
// Get Default Gateway IP
NetworkInfo.getGatewayIPAddress().then(defaultGateway => {
  console.log(defaultGateway);
});
```

```
import { NetworkInfo } from "react-native-network-info";

 _updateStates = () => {
    ...
    ...

    NetworkInfo.getGatewayIPAddress((gateway) => {
      console.log(gateway);
    });
  };
```

Comment: is it logging undefined or something else ?

Comment: it is logging nothing but the warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems , autolinking does not work properly for this library, i had to follow the following steps to make it work , [image]

It's noted in the documentation of the library for manual setup. But don't follow the 3rd step , otherwise your ios project won't build. I tried the following method from the library ,

```
NetworkInfo.getIPAddress().then((ipAddress) => {
      console.log(ipAddress);
    });
```

and it worked.

Comment: I am using expo, how can I get to those settings there? (and I am testing on Android, so I will follow the steps for manual linking for android)

Comment: it was actually probably something with linking, becauso without using expo it works!

Answer (score 0):

**You do not have added "then" in your code .Try this**

```
_updateStates = () => {
    ...
    ...

    NetworkInfo.getGatewayIPAddress().then(gateway => {
     console.log(gateway);
    });
  };
```

Comment: As I wrote: I already tried it this way (and tried it again right now). I still get exactly the same warning and nothing returned by the function.